# The type or namespace name 'form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 myform = new Form2();
            myform.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The following code should "launch" form2.  They are in the same project, and have the same namespace.  I don't understand.  I have tried changing the .NET framework from version 4 client to version 4.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code for form2? If it is in the same project, then the issue is going to be the namespace.

Comment: as @competent_tech said , you'd better post the code of Form2. And For the above source code you should got the error message with 'Form2' could not be found  , why it is "form2" in your title ?

Answer (score 3):

right click on Form2, chose "resolve" and pick one of the resolutions, alternatively move it to the `WindowsFormsApplication3` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I created `form2`, but renamed it later.

I found that although the name of the form changed, the name of the class remained as I originally created it.

For example:
1. **Project->Add Windows Form** (`Setup.cs`)
2. **File->Save Setup.cs as...** (`frmSetup.cs`)
3. Add code: frmSetup SetupForm = new frmSetup();

However, the actual name of the Setup class did not change with the file name, so changing my code to:

```
Setup SetupForm = new Setup();
```

So I was referencing the class name and not the file name solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had a similar renaming issue. I'd copied and renamed my project, so my namespaces didn't agree any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue in two wais:

1. You remove the namespace outside your form's class code or
2. Add a "using projectName" at the top of the code in your form.

Answer (score -1):

Both forms should have the same namespace

Comment: Do not pay attention to the downvote.. I just solved the problem and my answer is correct ! Thank you